# When (in the activity lifecycle) should I save?

Tags: android, android-activity

I basically have a form in my activity and I need to save it. I save it as an xml file. Right now, I'm saving it everytime `onPause()` is called but I think that's not the appropriate situation to do it. My question is when (in the activity lifecycle) should I save my form as an xml file? One other thing is that I need to set up some sort of form validation, too.

Comment: Why do you think onPause isn't appropriate?

Comment: Best way is to save in onPause() state

Comment: I think it might be getting called too often. Is it not? Plus, how to I setup the form validation if the form (activity) is not in view?

Comment: You can use onWindowFocusChanged Method to check if the activity is in Focus or not. Then you can take the appropriate actions in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what behavior you're trying to achieve. saving in onPause() can be absolutely fine, or you may want to save even more often, e.g. whenever the form input changes (by setting up change listeners) or validation succeeds.

For validation, you can do something like this:

```
public class YourTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        //... validation goes here
    }
}
```

and then, set it up like so:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new YourTextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 1):

All be depends on what do you want.

I thinks you must save form to xml file in `onSaveInstanseState`.

Answer (score 1):

onPause() is probably the best time for you to save your data because you can't guarantee that it wont be destroyed after that. Your other option in the lifecycle would be onStop() which is fine usually, but I see no reason why onPause() is 'inappropriate...'

You should probably save your data every time it is edited, that might be the most appropriate and the safest for your users...

Also, here is a form validation library that I use, very intuitive to use and pretty good with setting rules: [Android Saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar). (Easy install too, just drop the [jar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/downloads) in your libs folder)

Answer (score 0):

In `onPause` is the appropriate time. Every time when the Activity is no longer visible, it will be paused and therefore save.

To save the settings, you can use `SharedPreferences` or a custom format (you are using `XML`).
I prefer `SharedPreferences` because they are really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the form in onPause() seems to be appropiate .

Below Extract from the android developer docs supports it :

> Pause Your Activity When the system calls onPause() for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially
>   visible, but most often is an indication that the user is leaving the
>   activity and it will soon enter the Stopped state. You should usually
>   use the onPause() callback to:
>
> 1-Stop animations or other ongoing actions that could consume CPU.
>
> **2-Commit unsaved changes, but only if users expect such changes to be
>   permanently saved when they leave (such as a draft email).**
>
> 3- Release
>   system resources, such as broadcast receivers, handles to sensors
>   (like GPS), or any resources that may affect battery life while your
>   activity is paused and the user does not need them.

As far as form validation is concerned ,you can do it if you want to make sure that User has entered the required values.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created